# my Keras model does not predict negative values

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, regression

I would like to test NN model with keras using a dataset containing positive and negative continuous values. The keras model is as follows:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
#fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

#load and read dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("Phenols-toxicity.csv", delimiter=";")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,2:4]
Y = dataset[:,1]
print ("Variables: \n", X)
print ("Target_outputs: \n", Y)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.summary()
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['MSE'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, batch_size=10)
#make predictions (test)
F = model.predict(X)
print ("Predicted values: \n", F)
```

Everything seem going fine, However, all the negative values are predicted to zeros. Do the program soemwhere constrains values to be positive? 
My target values are as follow:

```
[ 0.085  2.468  0.07   0.68  -0.184  0.545 -0.063  0.871  0.113 -0.208
 0.688  1.638  2.03   0.078  0.573  1.036  0.015 -0.03  -0.381  0.701
 0.205  0.266  1.796  2.033  0.168  2.097  1.081 -0.384  0.377 -0.326
-0.143  1.292  0.701  0.334  1.157  1.638 -0.046  0.343  1.167  1.301
 0.277  1.131  0.471  0.617  0.707  0.185  0.604  0.017  0.381  0.804
 0.618  2.712 -0.092 -0.826  0.122  0.932  0.281  0.854  1.276  2.574
 1.125  0.73   0.796  1.145  1.569  2.664  0.034  1.398  0.393  0.612
-0.78   0.228 -1.043 -0.141  0.013  1.119  0.643 -0.242  0.757 -0.299
 0.599  0.36   1.778  0.053  1.268  1.276  0.516  1.167  1.638  0.478
 1.229  0.735  2.049 -0.064  1.201  1.41   1.295  0.798  1.854  0.16
-0.954  0.424 -0.51   1.638 -0.598  2.373  2.222 -0.358 -0.295  0.33
 0.183  0.122  1.745  0.081  2.097  0.914  0.979  0.084  0.473 -0.302
 0.879  0.366  0.172  0.45   1.307  0.886 -0.524  1.174 -0.512  0.939
 0.775 -1.053 -0.814  0.475 -1.021  1.42  -0.82   0.654  0.571 -0.076
 0.74   1.729  0.75   1.712  0.95   0.33   1.125  1.077  1.721  0.506
 0.539  0.266  1.745  1.229  0.632  1.585 -0.155  0.463  1.638  0.67
-0.155  2.053  0.379  0.181  0.253  1.356]
```

The predicted values are as follow:

```
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 2.03844833]
 [ 0.27423561]
 [ 0.59996957]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.44271404]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.47064281]
 [ 0.29890585]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.95044041]
 [ 1.84322166]
 [ 1.93953323]
 [ 0.18019629]
 [ 0.68691438]
 [ 0.96168059]
 [ 0.13934678]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.87886989]
 [ 0.30047321]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.90942693]
 [ 1.83728123]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.84627008]
 [ 1.25797462]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.01434445]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.1421392 ]
 [ 0.83652729]
 [ 0.37334418]
 [ 1.72099805]
 [ 1.73340106]
 [ 0.30456764]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.37316585]
 [ 1.34221601]
 [ 0.6739701 ]
 [ 0.79646528]
 [ 0.03717542]
 [ 0.35218674]
 [ 0.09512168]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.20107687]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.01262379]
 [ 1.00669646]
 [ 0.96650052]
 [ 2.10064697]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.25874525]
 [ 0.61007023]
 [ 0.68899512]
 [ 0.81215698]
 [ 0.88977867]
 [ 2.43740511]
 [ 1.00497019]
 [ 0.94933379]
 [ 0.83326894]
 [ 0.63394952]
 [ 1.27170706]
 [ 2.56578207]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.29493976]
 [ 0.599581  ]
 [ 0.63211834]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.31536853]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.02201092]
 [ 0.84008563]
 [ 0.73076451]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.4879511 ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.77698141]
 [ 0.66419512]
 [ 1.56657863]
 [ 0.25022489]
 [ 1.36990726]
 [ 1.50250816]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.61219454]
 [ 0.87011993]
 [ 0.72275633]
 [ 1.36519527]
 [ 0.72287238]
 [ 2.3798852 ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.23592615]
 [ 1.43725252]
 [ 0.95585048]
 [ 0.63723856]
 [ 1.8765614 ]
 [ 0.31583393]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.14386666]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.68151355]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.63394952]
 [ 1.97563386]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.38875413]
 [ 0.18854523]
 [ 0.23547113]
 [ 1.13463831]
 [ 0.30076784]
 [ 1.61114097]
 [ 0.93304199]
 [ 1.04891086]
 [ 0.26546735]
 [ 0.62234318]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.21855426]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.39396375]
 [ 0.45845711]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.4718284 ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.91218936]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.82205164]
 [ 0.78155482]
 [ 0.98432505]
 [ 2.15232277]
 [ 0.97631133]
 [ 0.59527659]
 [ 0.83814716]
 [ 0.80036032]
 [ 1.17462301]
 [ 0.51232517]
 [ 0.82968521]
 [ 0.9463613 ]
 [ 1.69353771]
 [ 1.21046495]
 [ 1.36349583]
 [ 0.94378138]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.98034143]
 [ 1.66670561]
 [ 0.52768588]
 [ 0.93855476]
 [ 1.26870298]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.69362605]]

[[ 0.        ]
 [ 2.03844833]
 [ 0.27423561]
 [ 0.59996957]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.44271404]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.47064281]
 [ 0.29890585]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.95044041]
 [ 1.84322166]
 [ 1.93953323]
 [ 0.18019629]
 [ 0.68691438]
 [ 0.96168059]
 [ 0.13934678]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.87886989]
 [ 0.30047321]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.90942693]
 [ 1.83728123]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.84627008]
 [ 1.25797462]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.01434445]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.1421392 ]
 [ 0.83652729]
 [ 0.37334418]
 [ 1.72099805]
 [ 1.73340106]
 [ 0.30456764]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.37316585]
 [ 1.34221601]
 [ 0.6739701 ]
 [ 0.79646528]
 [ 0.03717542]
 [ 0.35218674]
 [ 0.09512168]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.20107687]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.01262379]
 [ 1.00669646]
 [ 0.96650052]
 [ 2.10064697]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.25874525]
 [ 0.61007023]
 [ 0.68899512]
 [ 0.81215698]
 [ 0.88977867]
 [ 2.43740511]
 [ 1.00497019]
 [ 0.94933379]
 [ 0.83326894]
 [ 0.63394952]
 [ 1.27170706]
 [ 2.56578207]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.29493976]
 [ 0.599581  ]
 [ 0.63211834]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.31536853]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.02201092]
 [ 0.84008563]
 [ 0.73076451]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.4879511 ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.77698141]
 [ 0.66419512]
 [ 1.56657863]
 [ 0.25022489]
 [ 1.36990726]
 [ 1.50250816]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.61219454]
 [ 0.87011993]
 [ 0.72275633]
 [ 1.36519527]
 [ 0.72287238]
 [ 2.3798852 ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.23592615]
 [ 1.43725252]
 [ 0.95585048]
 [ 0.63723856]
 [ 1.8765614 ]
 [ 0.31583393]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.14386666]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.68151355]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.63394952]
 [ 1.97563386]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.38875413]
 [ 0.18854523]
 [ 0.23547113]
 [ 1.13463831]
 [ 0.30076784]
 [ 1.61114097]
 [ 0.93304199]
 [ 1.04891086]
 [ 0.26546735]
 [ 0.62234318]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.21855426]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.39396375]
 [ 0.45845711]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.4718284 ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.91218936]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.82205164]
 [ 0.78155482]
 [ 0.98432505]
 [ 2.15232277]
 [ 0.97631133]
 [ 0.59527659]
 [ 0.83814716]
 [ 0.80036032]
 [ 1.17462301]
 [ 0.51232517]
 [ 0.82968521]
 [ 0.9463613 ]
 [ 1.69353771]
 [ 1.21046495]
 [ 1.36349583]
 [ 0.94378138]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.98034143]
 [ 1.66670561]
 [ 0.52768588]
 [ 0.93855476]
 [ 1.26870298]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 1.69362605]]
```

Comment: you use relu activation in your last layer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you are constraining the negatives to zeros. The output activation is a ReLU, which does exactly that.

The solution is just to change the output activation to one that produces negative numbers, like the tanh. Note that the range of that activation is [-1, 1], so you will have to normalize your output labels to the same range.

Comment: Thx , but how to get back to the real values. Does it mean that I can do the same normalization with the ReLU activation function ?

Comment: @Dodilila You save the normalization factors and then you can easily invert the normalization (its a linear operation). Yes you can do the same with ReLU but then the ranges do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `linear` activation in the last layer but it might affect your model's learning speed. linear activation does not apply any activation function and outputs the sum of the incoming weights to the node as it is.

Comment: It is rare to expect the discriminative layer to be linear.